# gitlab variable is not accessible in the docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline using gitlab and now facing an issue with the gitlab variable. This is not accessible inside docker compose file.

this is my gitlab ci yml file

```
step-production:
  stage: production
  before_script:
    - export APP_ENVIRONMENT="$PRODUCTION_APP_ENVIRONMENT"
  only:
    - /^release.*$/
  tags:
    - release-tag
  script:
    - echo production env value is "$PRODUCTION_APP_ENVIRONMENT"
    - sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build --no-cache
    - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
  when: manual
```

and this is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        environment:
            - APP_ENVIRONMENT=${PRODUCTION_APP_ENVIRONMENT}
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        ports:
             - "8000:8000"
        restart: on-failure:5
        # network_mode: "host"
```

Can someone help me on how to access the gitlab variable inside docker compose file ? I have spend more than a day on the same issue

Comment: your config looks fine , however , what is the error message throwed by Gitlab ?

Comment: Its not showing any error message. I tried to access this variable from a python file inside the container, but its not working. if i hard code the value of APP_ENVIRONMENT in the docker compose file, then it will work

Comment: It's because `sudo` runs the command in a separate shell that doesn't carry the environment variables. Try adding `-E` flag to become `sudo -E` and see if it works. Otherwise, find a way to skip using sudo in the CI script.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by the following method

1. Edit the following line in gitlab ci yml file

```
    sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build --build-arg DB_NAME=$DEVELOPMENT_DB_NAME --build-arg DB_HOST=$DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST --no-cache
```

2. Define the value of $DEVELOPMENT_DB_NAME and $DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST in gitlab variables section
3. In the Docker file, add ARG and ENV sections as follows

```
ARG DB_NAME
ARG DB_HOST

ENV DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
ENV DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
```

Make sure that no environment variables with the same name are not defined in the docker-compose yml file

That's it !!!